# fancybox iframe will not open

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I implemented a script of a hotel booking form that opens in a fancybox iframe if they select a check-in and check-out date.

But now I want to link some other text/button links that also opens an fancybox iframe but with an oder url. I just don't know what to put in as a class in my  anchor.

The booking form should work and also the custom  links should open a fancybox iframe if i set a specific class to them.

Thanks for helping me out!

Head code:

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://loodsmans-texel.nl/other/bookingmodule/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="http://loodsmans-texel.nl/other/bookingmodule/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<!-- Optioneel -->
<link type="text/css" href="http://loodsmans-texel.nl/other/bookingmodule/defaultView.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<!-- Indien u nog geen jQuery gebruikt op uw website dient u deze ook in te laden -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.cubilis.eu/jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.cubilis.eu/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.cubilis.eu/jquery/date.js"></script>
<!-- Indien u nog geen Fancybox gebruikt op uw website dient u deze ook in te laden -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.cubilis.eu/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var _LOGISID = 3938;
    // Wijzig in uw gewenste taal (en, fr, nl, de, es, it)
    var _TAAL = 'nl';

    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#startdate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            });
            $("#enddate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            });
            var today = new Date();
            $("#startdate").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
            var tomorrow = today.add(3).days();
            $("#enddate").datepicker("setDate", tomorrow);

            $("#startdate").change(function () {
                var d = Date.parseExact($(this).val(), "dd-MM-yyyy");
                d = d.add(3).days();
                $("#enddate").datepicker("option", "minDate", d);
            });
        });

    function submitmyform(form) {
        var href = form.action + "?logisid=" + _LOGISID
            + "&taal=" + _TAAL + "&startdatum=" + $("#startdate").val() + "&einddatum=" + $("#enddate").val();
        jQuery.fancybox({ href: href ,type: 'iframe', width: 500, height: 550, overlayColor: '#000', hideOnContentClick: false, hideOnOverlayClick: false });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Body snipped of the booking form that opens a fancybox iframe:

```
 <form method="get" action="https://booking.cubilis.eu/check_availability.aspx" onsubmit="return submitmyform(this);">
<table id="CheckAvailabilityContainer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody id="bookmodule">
        <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="enddate" id="enddate" ></td>
        <td><input type="submit" class="btnCheckAvail" value="Book now" id="btnSubmit"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the textlink that should open an url in an fancybox iframe, that not work:

```
 <a href="https://booking.cubilis.eu/packages_select_dates.aspx?logisid=3938&amp;booktemplate=1&amp;taal=nl&amp;id=5920" title="Arrangement Fiets" class="jQuery fancybox.iframe">aangeboden</a>
```

What do I need to put in as a class?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to see what the browsers console is reporting back to you as in errors etc

Comment: It dont let me see which class I need to set in the <a> to activate the fancybox iframe... The bookingform is working. But i just need to know the class how i can activate the fancybox iframe in an custom href.  Thanks!

Comment: the problem is that the fancybox code is not being called: that is the function submitmyform() is not being called as far as i can see so is not initiating the fancybox code?

Comment: basically think about how this is called function submitmyform(form) {..} i tried it locally and placed the fancybox code outside and it popped up on load (after correcting the form and href vars)

Comment: And the bookingform is still working?

Comment: Could you give me the exact head code and <a> class? Thanks so much!

Comment: all i did to test this was place the following code outside the function and into the doc ready code:  jQuery.fancybox({ href: "ADD A HREF HERE" ,type: 'iframe', width: 500, height: 550, overlayColor: '#000', hideOnContentClick: false, hideOnOverlayClick: false });  then run the page and i got the pop up

Comment: Its not working for me..   What I need:  The bookingform is working as it should and opens a fancybox iframe by clicking on "Book now".          But now I want to have somewhere else on the page a text link, that if someone clicks on it an fancybox iframe will open with an url. (not the bookingform url)   The same as in this tutorial: http://www.urz.uni-heidelberg.de/online/imperia/javascript/fancybox_3.html       But this isnt working because the bookingform is added to the page.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you have your link as mentioned:

```
  <a href="https://booking.cubilis.eu/packages_select_dates.aspx?logisid=3938&amp;booktemplate=1&amp;taal=nl&amp;id=5920" title="Arrangement Fiets" onclick="Clickme(); return false;" class="jQuery fancybox.iframe">aangeboden</a>
```

Then i have added a function that is called when it is clicked:

```
    function Clickme(){
              jQuery.fancybox({href:'PLACE THE URL YOU REQUIRE HERE', type: 'iframe', width: 500, height: 550, overlayColor: '#000', hideOnContentClick: false, hideOnOverlayClick: false });
}
```

so what should happen is that onclick it should call that function (Clickme) then init fancybox

Comment: Where exactly should I add the function in the head? And why we need to put the url to open in the head and in the <a>?   Can you give me the entire head code here or on http://jsfiddle.net/?  Thanks! Sorry for asking so much!

Comment: the link would go where you want it and the say Clickme() function could go before or after your submitmyform(form) function.  you could remoeve the href:'??' bit as it should take the links url